# How to stop Google from changing results according to the links you press

Tags: google-search

Basically the title. I'm talking about how Google results seem to change to stuff about your region, and on links that you click often, it seems to rise to the top. Is there a way to stop that?

I already have Google set to Google.com, not a regional version.

Comment: Log out of Google and delete your cookies often. Always use http://google.com/ncr to search for stuff. That might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google customizes search results aggressively, and intentionally. It uses many parameters and sources to customize this, from complex, detailed analysis of your search and browsing history, to your location, social network activity, purchases, and even app and extension installation. Nobody knows the exact algorithms or the entire criteria.

**Searching while incognito and logged out of Google, is one of the best ways to nullify some of those automatic search customizations**, but unfortunately, Google always sees a location, and will always customize your results based on location. They see this as a core feature of Google search, not a bug, or even an option to be turned off. Even if you use a proxy or VPN, Google will customize based on the origin of the proxy or vpn, unless it knows your location through other settings.

For a bit more (albeit limited) information, see Google's [support page on location](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386?p=ws_settings_location&hl=en&rd=1). Notice there is no discussion of using *no location*.

Good luck.